# tyrus websocket connectToServer - how to clean up daemon threads

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

tyrus websockets ClientManager connectToServer 'Handshake response not received'

how do I retry the connection without more and more daemon and Grizzly-kernel and Grizzly-worker threads created.
Is there a call to Session or client to kill/cleanup
Thread-1 to 4 and Grizzly-kernel and Grizzly-worker threads?

Example JAVA main line which attempts forever to make and maintain a connection with a server which may not be running or is periodically restart.

---

```
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    latch.countDown();
}


enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        try {
            client.connectToServer(wsListener.class, new URI("wss://<host>/ws"));
            latch.await();
        }
        catch (DeploymentException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        client = null;
            latch = null;
            //  HERE... clean up 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

client.connectToServer returns Session instance and when you call Session.close(), client runtime should be shut down (no threads left).

You did not specify version of Tyrus you are using (I recommend 1.3.3, we made some improvements in this area). Also you might be interested in our shared container support, see [TYRUS-275](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS-275). You could combine it with [Thread pool config](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.3.3/org/glassfish/tyrus/container/grizzly/client/GrizzlyClientSocket.html#WORKER_THREAD_POOL_CONFIG) and you should have much better control of number of spawned/running threads.

We are always looking for new use cases, so if you think you have something which should be better supported in Tyrus, feel free to create new enhancement request on our [JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS).

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same behavior. I was using a lot of threads and synchronization and managed to accidently get the onOpen method of the ClientEndpoint blocking which caused the handshake to time out.